# How to get the <desc> description in Robot frame work

Tags: robotframework

I have to write a Robot test case to access the description on of svg which is mention using  tag in my code... It's something looks similar like below code.. How can i get that

````
     <svg>
         <desc>
               [ {"instance":"aaaa:bbbb","type":"cccc","x":"ss"}]                                      
          </desc>
    </svg>
</body>```       

I have used Get Text.. it didn't worked .. Any suggestion?
````

Answer (score 0):

What kind of locator you used?

It's not possible to locate svg elements using normal css or "normal" xpath. You need following construction:

```
//*[local-name()="svg"]/*[local-name()="desc"]
```

Additionally, depending on library you are using, `Get Text` keyword may not work and you will need to obtain properties of element.